# define __call__() dynamically during instance creation

Tags: python, class, methods, method-call

I have an instance `A` a which is called repeatedly like `A(i)`. Since this call is the bottleneck I want to code `A.__call__()` as perfomant as possible. Gains could be made if I can leverage the information which is available during instance creation, and select the call method based on this information, as in this mock example:

```py
class xxx():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        if kwargs["foo"] == "bar":
           self.__call__ = self.do_B
        else:
           self.__call__ = self.do_C

    def do_A(self):
        return 2
    def do_B(self):
        return 3

A = xxx(foo="bar")

A()
```

I am aware that there are plenty of posts on how to achieve this after the instance has been created, and that I could simply call `A._do_B(i)` in my code, but this would clutter the code with plenty of ifs and the above seems to be more natural (to me anyway :-)

Comment: Doesn't the example you provided work already?

Comment: It isn't obvious to me what the question is? Yes, something similar to this should work.

Comment: Magic methods are generally only looked for in the class, not in the instance.  One possibility: give your class a `__new__()` method, that instantiates one of two subclasses based on `kwargs["foo"]`, each of which contains a custom version of `.__call__()`.

Comment: I've edited the above code to be functional. If you run it will throw and error stating that A is not callable. I'll try @jasonharper approach

Comment: Since you've mentioned the error about "is not callable" I've found a question that had essentially the same problem - with some great answers and explanations. I hope the answers in the duplicate help you find a solution for your case.